# Show that $\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$ and $f-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$ are orthogonal.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

**Problem:** *"For $f,g$ in an inner product space, $g\neq0$, the projection of $f$ on $g$ is the vector, $\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$. Show that the two vectors $\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$ and $f-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$ are orthogonal."*

**Attempt:** $$\langle\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g,f-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g\rangle=\langle\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g,f\rangle-\langle\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g,\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g\rangle$$

$$=\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\langle g,f\rangle-\left|\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\right|^2\langle g,g\rangle$$

$$=\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\left(\langle g,f\rangle-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\langle g,g\rangle\right)$$

I'm not too sure where to go from here. I have a feeling that I should be making use of a geometric fact to do with how we have constructed $\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$ and $f-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, just use that fact that $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle g,f\rangle$ and that $\langle g,g\rangle=\|g\|^2$.

Comment: I see. I was overlooking the fact that I shouldn't be too quick to reformulate $\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\overline{\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}}$ as $\left(\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}\right)^2$. At least, this is important for when $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames I thought that you were working over the reals. The, it is more natural that the first step of your computation is$$\left\langle f-\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g,\frac{\langle f,\,g\rangle}{\|g\|^2}g\right\rangle.$$